# How to use url rewriting concept?

Tags: jsp, struts2

How to use URL rewriting in `<s:Form action="delete">` in this below code
how to resolve this error

```
  <s:iterator value="masterlist" var="item">
  <tr bordercolor="#E6E6E6"> 
  <td><a href="<s:url namespace="" action="uncchequepopulate1">
   <s:param name="chequeNumber" value="%{#item.chequeNo}" /></s:url>">
   <s:property value="%{#item.doncd}" />
  </a>
  </td>

  <td><s:property value="%{#item.dondesc}" /> </td> 
  <td><s:property value="%{#item.dondesce}" /></td> 
  <td><s:property value="%{#item.accno}" /></td>
   <center> <td>
   <s:form action="delete?doncod=<s:property value="%{#item.doncd}" />" >
    <s:submit value="Delete" theme="simple"></s:submit></s:form></td><center>

  <center> <td> <s:form action="modify" name="regform" id="formSelectOne"  theme="simple">
  <s:submit value="MODIFY" theme="simple"></s:submit></s:form></td> </center>
  </s:iterator>
```

how to resolve this error

```
   HTTP Status 500 - /Masterindex.jsp (line: 116, column: 60) Unterminated `<s:form>` tag this error will be display how to resolve
```

Comment: Don't nest tags like you do in `<s:form>` tag `action` attribute.

Comment: how to wtite url rewriting for doncd pls reply

Answer (score 0):

You can build the URL with the `s:url` tag with parameters before you use it with the form tag. The `s:form` tag uses the `action` attribute to map with the action but it also accept URLs if they are properly formatted. That what we will do now.

```
<s:url var="deleteUrl" action="delete" includeContext="false"><s:param name="doncod" value="%{#item.doncd}"/></s:url>
<s:form action="%{#deleteUrl.substring(1)}" method="POST">
```

Another approach, which most recommended is to use `hidden` field as request parameter to hold the value submitted with the form.

```
<s:form action="delete" method="POST">
<s:hidden name="doncod" value="%{#item.doncd}"/>
```

So, these two methods could be used to pass a parameter with the form action.